# Xamarin Managing Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to capture the stack trace thrown by my Xamarin app when an unhandled exception happens so that I can write a log to disk for reporting later.

Currently I am writing the exception and message to a string like so:

```
    private void OutputException(StringBuilder report, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception != null)
        {
            report.Append("\n\n");
            report.Append("\n\n");
            report.Append(exception.Message);
            report.Append("\n\n");
            report.Append(exception.StackTrace);

            OutputException(report, exception.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

I am using the same technique as described here:

https://peterno.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/unhandled-exception-handling-in-ios-and-android-with-xamarin/

Which attaches an event listener to

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

The code catches the stacktrace but when I look at the recorded trace it does not contain any of my class or method names:

```
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.26(intptr,intptr,intptr)
at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object.26(intptr,intptr,intptr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod 
(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, 
 Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0 
 at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, 
Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Throwable.get_Message () [0x0000a] in <6f8818d6ffa14f4bad6fb5f5d0f0e665>:0 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.Exception stack trace ---
```

java.lang.Exception:

How do I handle the exception and get it to produce class names that are in my code? I don't need the line numbers, I just need the class and method names.

Comment: Are you sure this is all there is? I have a feeling there should be more!

Comment: This is the top of the stack trace where I expect to see my class names. The rest of the stack is android references

Comment: It's not necessary that your unhandled exception is always from what you have coded, it could also be some of the libraries that you have in your application. Or it could be a bug with `Xamarin` or `Xamarin.Forms` or even `Android` itself keep that in mind as well.

Comment: I am testing this with a button that explicitly generates and exception. I know what the stack trace should look like and when I debug in VS then the debugger gives me the class/method names. However these are missing in the stack trace written to file. I can only assume that the VS debugger is doing additional work to display these.

Comment: @G.hakim your comment made me think and you were right. After my initial exception other exceptions were being thrown by the system. This was overwriting my previous error file. I have now update the code to append rather than overwrite. Thanks for the prompt.